# How can I fix JSON-1.7.5 and UTF-8 encoding errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, utf-8, rspec

I'm having problems with a report (covering models with spec tests).
My gems:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '3.4.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.0'
  gem 'guard-bundler', '1.0.0'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem "shoulda-matchers", '1.1.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  #gem "simplecov-rcov", "~> 0.2.3"
gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'json_spec'
end
```

Error message:

```
Finished in 1.21 seconds
9 examples, 0 failures
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `encode': "\xD1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `generate'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `pretty_generate'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/result_merger.rb:77:in `block in store_result'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/result_merger.rb:75:in `open'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/result_merger.rb:75:in `store_result'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov.rb:48:in `result'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/configuration.rb:133:in `block in at_exit'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:51:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/simplecov-0.6.4/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb:51:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

How this can be solved? Please help!

**Update**
What i've done:
1) uninstalled & reinstalled all gems http://axonflux.com/uninstalling-and-reinstalling-all-ruby-gems
2) deleted the .rvn dir
3) commented out some gems

```
group :development do
#  gem 'growl'
group :test do
# gem 'json_spec'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  #gem "simplecov-rcov", "~> 0.2.3"
```

4)installed rvn
no luck on any of those stages ....
have to find where those offending characters are exactly!

**UPDATE**
Tried setting  Encoding.default_external =  :'ASCII-8BIT' | :'UTF-8' in boot.rb. no luck

**UPDATE**
Trying to solve problem by running a script

```
  #!/bin/bash
    FROM=us-ascii
    TO=UTF-8
    ICONV="iconv -f $FROM -t $TO"
    # Convert
    find gazsev32/ -type f -name "*" | while read fn; do
    cp ${fn} ${fn}.bak
    $ICONV < ${fn}.bak > ${fn}
    rm ${fn}.bak
    done
```

**UPDATE**
In the end i'm afraid it's time to reinstall my system. System errors followed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UTF-8 Encoding

Your trace says:

> /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `encode': "\xD1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

This is clearly an encoding error, which is a common problem under Ruby 1.9. It can sometimes be solved by ensuring that you have:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of your source files, but if not you may need to resort to using */usr/bin/iconv* from the shell or some Ruby brute force to remove offending characters before trying to convert your code to JSON. The problem is clearly in your JSON library, but the offending characters are probably elsewhere in your source.

Comment: I'm using  magic_encoding gem. all files should have encoding set in comments